# How to write rows into txt file python

Tags: python-2.7, file, rows

I have code to write files to writer and then use writer to write into csv.
This is all using 'import csv' library.
But the problem is, I have numbers like 123456789.123456789 and when it writes into csv the number got truncate into 123456789.1234. so I want to write the results to txt instead, but don't know how to write rows to txt.

```
  if results.get('rows', []):
   for row in results.get('rows'):
     for i in range(len(row)):
       old, new = row[i], str()
       for s in old:
        new += s if s in string.printable else ''
       row[i]=new
     writer.writerow(row)



path = '/Users/sailormoon/Desktop/' 
filename = 'sailormoon.csv' 
with open(path + filename, 'wt') as f:
 writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
```

Pseudo code I think:

```
path = '/Users/sailormoon/Desktop/' 
filename = 'sailormoon.txt' 
with open(path + filename, 'wt') as f:
 f.write(row)
```

what library I can use to write rows into txt for python? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Append all your numbers to a list as strings. Then use a `for` loop:

```
numbers = ['123456789.123456789', '123453459.128967678']

with open(path + '\\numbers.txt', 'w') as out:
    for n in numbers:
        out.write(n + '\n')
```